# Usage of particles with 出てくる

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-から

> 初めて[山奥]{やまおく}から町に出てきた村の人たちは見るものすべてに[驚]{おどろ}いた。

In this instance, does 山奥から町に出てきた mean "left the mountains and came to the city" (町)? Also, I would normally interpret 出てくる as "leave and come back", but maybe from the viewpoint of someone in the city it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 出る means simply "to go out/leave/exit" with no sense of direction with respect to the speaker
- 出ていく means "to go out [away from the speaker]"
- 出てくる means "to come out [toward the speaker]"

In other words, the sentence is written from the point of view of someone in the city.

> 初めて山奥から町に出てきた村の人たちは見るものすべてに驚いた。
>   The villagers, coming out of the mountains for the first time, were surprised about everything they saw.

Answer (score -1):

verb-てくる means doing the verb and come (not necesseraly back).
badly translated, 出てくる means to get out and come.

The first time the members of the village got out from the mountain and came to the city, they were surprised by everything they saw.