# Is 包囲に出てくる a fixed collocation?

Tags: collocations

Imagine if a soldier broke out of an encirclement and retreated away. Should enemies still use 包囲に出てくる instead of 包囲に出て行く?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12708/41444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standpoint of the encircling enemy, one may say either あの兵士は包囲に向かってきた (when he is still within the encirclement trying to break out) or あの兵士は包囲から出ていった (when he has already broken out of the encirclement and gone away).

包囲に出てくる may make sense when the soldier is getting out of something (e.g., a trench) and then approaching the observer (i.e., an encircling enemy). 包囲に出ていく makes sense from the standpoint of the soldier or someone next to him, but the encircling side would not say this.